# How to make size of Window responsive for every type of screen resolution using WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

My Windows Form is responsive at height=600,Width=1050.I am using grid,every thing is set in rows and columns,and grids inside the columns and rows.
I want that this form should be responsive on every resolution like i pasted image given below.So what should I do for it?????

```
<Window x:Class="GiorgentiWPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="1050" MinHeight="600" MinWidth="1050" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
<Grid Width="auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="#FFE8E8E8">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="90*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="431*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="60*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="933*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="37" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Width="1042" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="37" Margin="3,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="46" RenderTransformOrigin="0.475,0.472"/>

        <Menu HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="56,0,0,10" Width="auto" Background="Transparent">

                <MenuItem Header="_File" Height="30" FontSize="15" FontStretch="SemiExpanded">
                    <MenuItem Header="Tools">
                        <MenuItem Header="Print Designer"/>
                        <MenuItem Header="User Information"/>
                        <MenuItem Header="Addons"/>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem Header="Performance">
                        <MenuItem Header="Compnay" Background="#FFCB5A5A"/>
                        <MenuItem Header="WorkStation"/>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem Header="Hardware Setup Wizard"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Clock In/Out"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Exit"/>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="_Point Of Sale" Height="auto" FontSize="15" FontStretch="SemiExpanded">
                    <MenuItem Header="New Sales Receipt"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="New Return Receipt"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="New Payment"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="New Sales Order"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="New Layaway"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="New WorkOrder"/>
                    <MenuItem Header= "Sales History"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Held Receipt "/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Sales Order Lists"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Layaway List"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Work Order List"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Open Cash Drawer     Ctrl+F8"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="End Of Day Procedure"/>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="_Customer" Height="auto" FontSize="15" FontStretch="SemiExpanded">
                    <MenuItem Header="New Customer"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Customer List"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Record Manager"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Create an E-mail Campaign"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Customer Center"/>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="_Inventory" Height="auto" FontSize="15" FontStretch="SemiExpanded">
                    <MenuItem Header="New Item"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="New Quantity Adjustment"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="New Cost Adjustment"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="New Transfer Slip"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Item List"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Department List"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Quantity Adjustment History "/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Cost Adjustment History"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Held Cost Adjustment Memos"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Transfer History"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Held Transfer Slip"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Remainder"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Start Physical Inventory"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Price Manager"/>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="_Purchasing" Height="auto" FontSize="15" FontStretch="SemiExpanded">
                    <MenuItem Header="Receive Item"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Return Voucher "/>
                    <MenuItem Header="New Purchase Order"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="New Vendor"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Receiving History"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Held Vochers"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Purchase Order List"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Vender List"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Suggest PO"/>

                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="_Employee" Height="auto" FontSize="15" FontStretch="SemiExpanded">
                    <MenuItem Header="Employee List"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Security"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Change Employee Password"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Clock In/Out"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="New Employee Time Entry"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Time Clock History"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Manage Clocked-in Employee"/>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="_Report" Height="auto" FontSize="15" FontStretch="SemiExpanded">
                    <MenuItem Header="Report Center"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Dashboard"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="View Drawer Count History"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Merchant Service Center"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Sales"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Cash Drawer"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Payments"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Customers"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Items"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Purchasing"/>
                </MenuItem>
            </Menu>
    </Grid>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="533" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" Grid.Row="1" Margin="21,0,0,0" Background="#FFE8E8E8">
        <Button Content="I Want To....&#xD;&#xA;" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="140" RenderTransformOrigin="0.35,-0.455" Height="55" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" TextOptions.TextHintingMode="Animated">
            <Button.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFF3F3F3"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFEBEBEB" Offset="0.5"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFDDDDDD" Offset="0.5"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF5DA62A" Offset="0.5"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF539B23" Offset="0.483"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
        <Button Content="Make a Sale&#xD;&#xA;" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,75,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="140" RenderTransformOrigin="0.35,-0.455" Height="55" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold">
            <Button.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFF3F3F3" Offset="0.096"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFEBEBEB" Offset="0.5"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF7590D3" Offset="0.5"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF7590D3" Offset="1"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF7590D3" Offset="0.257"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFF3F3F3" Offset="0.087"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF7590D3" Offset="0.087"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF7590D3" Offset="0.035"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF7590D3" Offset="0.13"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF7590D3" Offset="0.413"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF7590D3" Offset="0.478"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF7590D3" Offset="0.009"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF7590D3" Offset="0.078"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF7590D3" Offset="0.1"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF7590D3" Offset="0.091"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF7590D3" Offset="0.096"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF7590D3" Offset="0.487"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
        <Button Content="Receive Items&#xD;&#xA;" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,140,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="140" RenderTransformOrigin="0.35,-0.455" Height="55" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold">
            <Button.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF7590D3" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFEBEBEB" Offset="0.5"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF7590D3" Offset="0.5"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF7590D3" Offset="1"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF7590D3" Offset="0.291"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF7590D3" Offset="0.496"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF7590D3" Offset="0.5"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
        <Button Content="Inventory" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,205,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="140" RenderTransformOrigin="0.35,-0.455" Height="55" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold">
            <Button.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF7590D3" Offset="0.5"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFEBEBEB" Offset="0.5"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF7590D3" Offset="0.5"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF7590D3" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
        <Button Content="Reports" Margin="10,270,0,203" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="140" Height="55" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold">
            <Button.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF7590D3" Offset="0.5"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFEBEBEB" Offset="0.5"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF7590D3" Offset="0.5"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF7590D3" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>

        <Button Content="End Of Day&#xD;&#xA;" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,335,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="140" RenderTransformOrigin="0.35,-0.455" Height="55" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14">
            <Button.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF7590D3" Offset="0.5"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFEBEBEB" Offset="0.5"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF7590D3" Offset="0.5"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF7590D3" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
        <Button Content="Credit Cards" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,400,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="140" RenderTransformOrigin="0.35,-0.455" Height="55" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold">
            <Button.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF7590D3" Offset="0.5"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFEBEBEB" Offset="0.5"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF7590D3" Offset="0.5"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF7590D3" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="530" Margin="10,3,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="auto" >
        <Grid.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFFCFCFC" Offset="0.423"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFEAEAEA" Offset="0.611"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFFCFCFC" Offset="0.816"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFFCFCFC" Offset="0.251"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Grid.Background>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="323*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="33*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="496*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="43*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="359*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="20*">
                <RowDefinition.BindingGroup>
                    <BindingGroup/>
                </RowDefinition.BindingGroup>
            </RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="95*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="36" Margin="174,6,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Qiuck Find Customer, Item ,Receipt, Help and more" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="auto" FontStyle="Italic" RenderTransformOrigin="0.502,0.239" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>

            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="344" Margin="30,4,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="286" RenderTransformOrigin="0.447,0.514">
            <Grid.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect/>
            </Grid.Effect>
            <Grid.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFDFE8F5" Offset="0.504"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFAFBFC" Offset="0.726"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFDFE9F5" Offset="0.322"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Grid.Background>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="38*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="266*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="37*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="-0.177"/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Grid.RenderTransform>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="88,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Search Message" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="186" RenderTransformOrigin="0.489,0.419" FontStyle="Italic"/>
            <Label Grid.Row="0" Content="Message" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="13,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>


            <Button Grid.Row="2" Content="New" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="13,3,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="58" RenderTransformOrigin="0.35,-0.455" Height="19" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="10">
                <Button.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF7590D3" Offset="0.5"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFEBEBEB" Offset="0.5"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF7590D3" Offset="0.5"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF7590D3" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Button.Background>
            </Button>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="213,10,0,0"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top">
               <Hyperlink NavigateUri="" >Show List</Hyperlink>
            </TextBlock>
            <ScrollViewer Height="216" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,10,0,0" >
                <StackPanel>
                <RichTextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="162" Margin="40,27,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="171" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Grid.Row="1">
                    <RichTextBox.RenderTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <ScaleTransform/>
                            <SkewTransform/>
                            <RotateTransform Angle="-12.787"/>
                            <TranslateTransform/>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </RichTextBox.RenderTransform>
                    <FlowDocument>
                        <Paragraph>
                            <Run Text="RichTextBox"/>
                        </Paragraph>
                    </FlowDocument>
                </RichTextBox>

                <RichTextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="172" Margin="40,27,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="171" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                    <RichTextBox.RenderTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <ScaleTransform/>
                            <SkewTransform/>
                            <RotateTransform Angle="-12.787"/>
                            <TranslateTransform/>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </RichTextBox.RenderTransform>
                    <FlowDocument>
                        <Paragraph>
                            <Run Text="RichTextBox"/>
                        </Paragraph>
                    </FlowDocument>
                </RichTextBox>
                </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="280" Margin="10,10,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="5" Background="#FFE7E7E7"/>
        <Grid Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="345" Margin="10,4,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="476">
            <Grid.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFE1EAF6" Offset="0.51"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFF8FAFC" Offset="0.636"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Grid.Background>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="28*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="16*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="32*"/>


                <RowDefinition Height="46*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="24*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="45*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="21*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="44*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="21*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="63*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,5,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="16" Height="21" Width="116">
               <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://search.msn.com" FontWeight="ExtraBlack">Getting Started</Hyperlink>
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="180,5,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="16" RenderTransformOrigin="0.774,0.578" Height="21" Width="85">
                <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://search.msn.com" FontWeight="ExtraBlack">Navigator</Hyperlink>
            </TextBlock>

            <GridSplitter HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="18" Margin="162,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="2" Background="Gray"/>
            <GridSplitter HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="438" Margin="234,-183,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="4" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Grid.RowSpan="8" Background="Gray">
                <GridSplitter.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform/>
                        <SkewTransform/>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                        <TranslateTransform/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </GridSplitter.RenderTransform>
            </GridSplitter>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,10,0,0" Grid.Row="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Welcome to Quick Book Point Of Sales 10.0 " VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Gray" Height="21" Width="331"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,10,0,0" Grid.Row="3" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Ringing up your first sale " VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="14" FontWeight="SemiBold" Foreground="Gray" Height="19" Width="163"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,29,0,0" Grid.Row="3" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Learn how to make a sale, take a payment and print a receipt." VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="331" Height="14" Foreground="#FFB5A99C"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="280,2,0,0" Grid.Row="4" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="20" Width="89">
              <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http:www.google.com.pk">Make a sale now</Hyperlink>
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="385,2,0,0" Grid.Row="4" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="20" Width="89">
              <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http:www.google.com.pk">Learn more</Hyperlink>
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,8,0,0" Grid.Row="5" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Adding Items " VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="14" FontWeight="SemiBold" Foreground="Gray" Height="19" Width="163"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,28,0,0" Grid.Row="5" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Learn how to add items to your inventory." VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="331" Height="14" Foreground="#FFB5A99C" RenderTransformOrigin="0.47,4.735"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="280,3,0,0" Grid.Row="6" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.544,-0.568" Width="89">
                <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http:www.google.com.pk">Open the item list</Hyperlink>
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="385,2,0,0" Grid.Row="6" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <Hyperlink NavigateUri="">Learn More</Hyperlink>
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,2,0,0" Grid.Row="7" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Customizing Point of sale   " VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="14" FontWeight="SemiBold" Foreground="Gray" Height="19" Width="163"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,22,0,0" Grid.Row="7" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Learn how to add items to your inventory." VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="331" Height="14" Foreground="#FFB5A99C" RenderTransformOrigin="0.47,4.735"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="280,3,0,0" Grid.Row="8" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <Hyperlink NavigateUri="">Open preferences</Hyperlink>
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="385,3,0,0" Grid.Row="8" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <Hyperlink NavigateUri="">Learn More</Hyperlink>
            </TextBlock>
        </Grid>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="414,2,0,0" Grid.Row="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="2">
            <Hyperlink NavigateUri="">Close</Hyperlink>
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="106,18,0,0" Grid.Row="3" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Accepted Credit Cards " VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="213" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FF5C7B3C"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="106,62,0,0" Grid.Row="3" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Save time and money.Accept credit cards directly in Point of Sale. " VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Width="353" Height="22"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="106,62,0,0" Grid.Row="3" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Hyperlink NavigateUri="">Learn More</Hyperlink>
        </TextBlock>




    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

Comment: **I want that this form should be responsive on every resolution like i pasted image given below.** You can paste any image if you are a new user; So can you explain more about **responsive on every resolution** statement in detail?

Comment: Actually 10 points are needed to paste  the image.unfortunately i didn't have.my window form is responsive at  height=600,Width=1050.I want this at full resolution at every resolution using WPF.When I display this form on full resolution ,the components of form are set according to 1050x600,and blank space is below and sides of this form.kindly read the code.and help me about this issue.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood from your comment, you want your window to wrap its contents. You can use `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` and `VerticalAlignment="Stretch"` for your grids so that they will get stretched as window resizes. Also avoid fixed values like `Height="34"` etc. wherever possible to make it "responsive". Refer following links for more guidance about `Grid`.

- [The Grid - Rows & columns](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/panels/grid-rows-and-columns/)
- [Grid Panel](http://wpftutorial.net/GridLayout.html)

Comment: Thanks alot for helping about this,issue is resolved

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it has resolved your issue. This will mark the question as answered.